# Phone number validation using zend framwork

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I am using below code to validate by phone number in my project,

```
$phone = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('phone', array(
      'label' => $view->_('phone'),
      'value' => '',
      'class' => 'text-size text hastip',
      'title' => $qtips_messages['key_phone'],
      'required' => true,
      'tabindex' => '13',
      'validators' => array(
                                array('Digits', false, array(
                    'messages' => array(
                        'notDigits'     => "Phone Invalid Digits, ex. 1234567890",
                        'digitsStringEmpty' => "",
                    ))),
                array('notEmpty', true, array(
                    'messages' => array(
                        'isEmpty'   =>  'Phone can\'t be empty'
                    )
                )),
                array('StringLength', false, array(10, 10, 'messages' => array(
                            'stringLengthInvalid'           => "Phone Length Invalid entry",
                            'stringLengthTooShort'          => "Phone Invalid Length , ex. 1234567890"
                    ))),
            ),
      'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
      'decorators' => $this->requiredElementDecorators,
      'description' => '<img src="'.$baseurl.'/images/star.png" alt="required" />',
      'filters' => array('StringTrim')
    ));
    $this->addElement($phone);
```

This works well when field is empty,invalid,length. my requirement is ,phone field should accept spaces also like `123 456 7890`. 
Kindly advice on this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure how the digits validator handles the spaces but I guess it won't allow them (or you wouldn't be posting here). So instead of using the digits validator, change it for a regex validator. I'm not good with regex so instead of me giving you the expression I suggest you take a look at the following page containing several expressions for phonenumbers: [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Adding the validator should look something like:

```
array('regex', false, array('/^[0-9 ]+$/'))
```

Like I said, I'm no good with regex so the regex itself might not be completely accurate, but adding a validator like that should solve your problem.